# The Java code did not show the result that I want

Tags: java

I am new to Java and actually this code is to ask the user for 2 numbers for the conversion from inch to centimeter and vice versa. But when I built it, it said "error: cannot find symbol" and I still cannot figure it out although I kept checking the code. Below is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.DecimalFormat;

public class Practical2Q2 {

    public Practical2Q2() {}

    public static void inchToCentimeter(double a) {
        System.out.println("Inches      " + "Centimeters");
        System.out.print("\n");

        for (double i = 1.0; i <= a; i++) {
            double cm = i * 2.54;
            System.out.println(i + "        " + df.format(cm));
        }
    }

    public static void centimeterToInch(double b) {
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.println("Centimeters     " + "Inches");
        System.out.print("\n");

        for (double i = 5.0; i <= b; i += 5) {
            double inch = i / 2.54;
            System.out.println(i + "        " + df.format(inch));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner newScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        System.out.println("Please enter 2 numbers :\n" + "Number a for the conversion from inch to centimeter,\n"
                + "while number b for the conversion from centimeter to inch");
        System.out.println("Number a : ");
        double c = newScanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Number b : ");
        double d = newScanner.nextDouble();
        inchToCentimeter(c);
        centimeterToInch(d);
    }
}
```

Could you please state the wrong part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created `DecimalFormat df` in the main method, it means that you can't access to it outside the method. I'v edited your code and i've created the field `DecimalFormat df` outside the main method.

I also changed the `for loop` inside the `centimetersToInch()` method, now it prints out all the values like in the `inchToCentimeters()` method.

Here's the code:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

static DecimalFormat df;

public static void inchToCentimeter(double a)

{
    System.out.println("Inches      " + "Centimeters");
    System.out.print("\n");

    for (double i = 1.0; i <= a; i++)

    {
        double cm = i * 2.54;
        System.out.println(i + "        " + df.format(cm)); 
    }
} 

public static void centimeterToInch(double b)

{
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.println("Centimeters     " + "Inches");
    System.out.print("\n");

    for (double i = 1.0; i <= b; i++)

    {
        double inch = i / 2.54;
        System.out.println(i + "        " + df.format(inch)); 
    }
 }

  public static void main(String args[])

  {
    Scanner newScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    System.out.println("Please enter 2 numbers :\n" + "Number a for the conversion from inch to centimeter,\n"
        + "while number b for the conversion from centimeter to inch");
    System.out.println("Number a : ");
    double c = newScanner.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Number b : ");
    double d = newScanner.nextDouble();
    inchToCentimeter(c);
    centimeterToInch(d);
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your variable df is local only to your main method. Methods inchToCentimeter and centimeterToInch are unaware of this variable. Either make it a global variable or pass it as arguements to these methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your `df` variable is not in there. Add the following line in your code.

```
static DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
```

Declare `df` variable as instance variable.

Comment: I haven't learnt this yet,but anyway thanks for your response.

Comment: Yes,because you enable me to know the existence of the "static" keyword.